# ¿Existe algún orden de ejecución en los middleware de Laravel 5.5 (o mayor)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando en la una aplicación hecha en `Laravel` 5.5, donde he tenido problemas a la usar los `middleware`, especialmente en la parte de autentificación de usuarios, para trabajar con usuarios en `Laravel` existe una forma propuesta por el mismo framework que se indica en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication). En la aplicación que estoy trabajando ya estaba las clases de autenficación creadas, y pude notar que en los constructores de dichas clases se llamaba a ciertos middleware por ejemplo, en la clase `LoginController`:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['guest', 'othermiddleware'])->except('logout');
    }
```

pero también se llamaba a los middleware dentros de la rutas de la aplicación como por ejemplo:

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'index', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'othermiddleware']], function () { ... code ...}
```

Mi duda con esto es sí existe alguna **precedencia** en cuanto se llaman a los middlewares porque a veces me funcionan y otras no para los eventos que están definidos.

Comment: ¿Se refiere al orden en que se llaman los middleware?

Comment: Sí, con precedencia me refiero si hay algún orden, o sí alguno prevalece sobre otro, es decir, si se crea una instancia de login se toman solo esos middleware, o también se consideran los de las rutas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos los middleware son ejecutados, siempre y cuando hayan sido correctamente definidos, sean en rutas, constructores, etc.

Para los middleware con prioridad «normal» no existe un orden específico como tal, y esto siempre ha generado cierta controversia en la comunidad Laravel, lo que pasa es que la gran mayoría de desarrolladores no conocen la solución a esto.

Si se necesita un orden específico, se puede recurrir a la propiedad `$middlewarePriority` del archivo Kernel.php, **PERO** al momento de definirlo y hacer un override se debe tener en cuenta lo que ya está definido en `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel`:

```
/**
 * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
 *
 * Forces the listed middleware to always be in the given order.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
```

Los middleware que estén en dicho array se ejecutarán estrictamente en el orden que están ahí, y se recomienda mantener este orden al hacer el override respectivo.

Si deseas entender cómo Laravel organiza la ejecución de los middleware, entonces deberás revisar el enrutador, donde se recolectan TODOS los middleware definidos en la aplicación según la ruta.

A continuación el código que organiza, definido en `Illuminate\Routing\Router`:

```
/**
 * Gather the middleware for the given route with resolved class names.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
 * @return array
 */
public function gatherRouteMiddleware(Route $route)
{
    $middleware = collect($route->gatherMiddleware())->map(function ($name) {
        return (array) MiddlewareNameResolver::resolve($name, $this->middleware, $this->middlewareGroups);
    })->flatten();

    return $this->sortMiddleware($middleware);
}

/**
 * Sort the given middleware by priority.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $middlewares
 * @return array
 */
protected function sortMiddleware(Collection $middlewares)
{
    return (new SortedMiddleware($this->middlewarePriority, $middlewares))->all();
}
```

Vemos que llama a la clase SortedMiddleware, la cual realiza el ordenamiento definitivo, y su código más relevante es:

```
/**
 * Create a new Sorted Middleware container.
 *
 * @param  array  $priorityMap
 * @param  array|Collection  $middlewares
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(array $priorityMap, $middlewares)
{
    if ($middlewares instanceof Collection) {
        $middlewares = $middlewares->all();
    }

    $this->items = $this->sortMiddleware($priorityMap, $middlewares);
}

/**
 * Sort the middlewares by the given priority map.
 *
 * Each call to this method makes one discrete middleware movement if necessary.
 *
 * @param  array  $priorityMap
 * @param  array  $middlewares
 * @return array
 */
protected function sortMiddleware($priorityMap, $middlewares)
{
    $lastIndex = 0;

    foreach ($middlewares as $index => $middleware) {
        if (! is_string($middleware)) {
            continue;
        }

        $stripped = head(explode(':', $middleware));

        if (in_array($stripped, $priorityMap)) {
            $priorityIndex = array_search($stripped, $priorityMap);

            // This middleware is in the priority map. If we have encountered another middleware
            // that was also in the priority map and was at a lower priority than the current
            // middleware, we will move this middleware to be above the previous encounter.
            if (isset($lastPriorityIndex) && $priorityIndex < $lastPriorityIndex) {
                return $this->sortMiddleware(
                    $priorityMap, array_values($this->moveMiddleware($middlewares, $index, $lastIndex))
                );
            }

            // This middleware is in the priority map; but, this is the first middleware we have
            // encountered from the map thus far. We'll save its current index plus its index
            // from the priority map so we can compare against them on the next iterations.
            $lastIndex = $index;
            $lastPriorityIndex = $priorityIndex;
        }
    }

    return array_values(array_unique($middlewares, SORT_REGULAR));
}
```

No voy a explicar lo que hace el código, ya que como buen programador que eres, puedes ir analizándolo y apoyarte en la documentación de PHP.